# baselinestretch outside of LaTeX preamble?

Tags: line-spacing

What is the difference, in LaTeX's head, between these two documents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

...and...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The first doesn't result in a double spaced document, I feel it should. Is it only possible to set `\baselinestretch` in the preamble, or can it be changed part way through a document?

(Note: I'm using the `setspace` package for double spacing, I'm curious mostly as to the behavior of `\baselinestretch` here...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to use `\selectfont` after you change `\baselinestretch` in the first example.